# How to call a rest service with client certificate using the feign client

Tags: client-certificates, feign

I want to access a rest service which is secured by a client certificate. The server will only accept requests if the correct certificate is presented. We are using the Feign client in our project and I could not find an example for solving this problem. Is it added as an interceptor?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by creating a Custom Feign Configuration as below:

```kotlin
class CustomFeignConfiguration {

    private val log = Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass.name)

    @Value("\${client_p12_base64_encoded_string}")
    private val clientP12: String = ""

    @Value("\${client_p12_password}")
    private val clientP12Pass: String = ""

    @Bean
    fun feignClient(): Client {
        val sslSocketFactory= getSSLSocketFactory()
        log.info("CUSTOM FEIGN CLIENT CALLED")
        return Client.Default(sslSocketFactory, DefaultHostnameVerifier())
    }

    private fun getSSLSocketFactory(): SSLSocketFactory {
        val decoder = java.util.Base64.getDecoder()
        val p12 = decoder.decode(clientP12)
        val p12File = File("clientCer.p12")
        p12File.writeBytes(p12)

        try {
            val sslContext = SSLContexts
                .custom()
                .loadKeyMaterial(p12File, clientP12Pass.toCharArray(), clientP12Pass.toCharArray())
                .build()
            return sslContext.socketFactory
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(exception)
        }

    }
}
```

The FeignClient interface that is using the configuration has to load this specifically

```kotlin
@FeignClient(name = "client", configuration = [CustomFeignConfiguration::class], url = "\${url}")
interface Client {
  ....
  ....
}
```

The SSLContexts library can only use p12 certificates and we have to convert the certificates and keys in PEM format to the P12 format.

Create a p12 certificate from your PEM certificate and key using the following SSL command:

```shell
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey domain.key -in domain.crt -out domain.p12
```

Please record the password that you enter after you run this command.

Convert this p12 certificate to a base64 string using the following command

```shell
base64 domain.p12 > domain.p12.base64
```

Convert this multiline string to a single line string using the following command:

```shell
tr -d "\n\r" < domain.p12.base64 > domain.p12.base64.singleline
```

Use the single line string from this command and the password that you recorded earlier in your **application.properties**.

Comment: How can i verify if certificate is being used for the requests?